# Facebook API in Java - restfb

Tags: java, json, facebook, api, restfb

I try to use restfb to communicate with Facebook API and I can not get the thing - why in some cases I have to use fetchObject method and in other I have to use fetchConnection?
[Example](https://github.com/restfb/restfb-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/restfb/example/GraphReaderExample.java)

```
FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(fbToken, Version.LATEST);
client.fetchObject("me", User.class);
client.fetchConnection("me/friends", User.class);
```

Though if I use browser links I only add parameters to the query: fields=id or fields=friends:
[id](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me?access_token=EAAEEld0FQC4BAItilRD9GWJB2Rgka2IJ0xJaDCltMrZBhqEdRsyjGqgyj8bqNRCeGGlavQ2mzgSPJ4CxwJP5VMZBDGwPZAbwrhO4Y4l7KKYmS7bIezZA1Ovqir9zVumoBq9VH2KvZB1quogJ4bDkAlvkGZB1MbAZC31wqgo8SwJjADMmXh0N8KF6WXPdEJZC5vir5UHeza5wZBQZDZD&fields=id) and [friends](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me?access_token=EAAEEld0FQC4BAItilRD9GWJB2Rgka2IJ0xJaDCltMrZBhqEdRsyjGqgyj8bqNRCeGGlavQ2mzgSPJ4CxwJP5VMZBDGwPZAbwrhO4Y4l7KKYmS7bIezZA1Ovqir9zVumoBq9VH2KvZB1quogJ4bDkAlvkGZB1MbAZC31wqgo8SwJjADMmXh0N8KF6WXPdEJZC5vir5UHeza5wZBQZDZD&fields=id)

Thank you for the answers

Comment: fetchConnection will return a list of Objects. fetchObject will return one Object.

Comment: Is that the only difference that fetchConnection has data() method that has the list of objects?

Comment: if fetchConnection is used properly, you don't have to care about the paging. Check the documentation and the examples there...